# Regex to avoid all zero in the masked text box

Tags: c#, angularjs, regex

I want to avoid "000-000-0000" in my text box.

```
<div class="inner-addon right-addon">
                                <input id="PhoneHtmlId" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="12" autocomplete="off" patternValidator=""
                                       validation [controlRef]="form.controls.HomePhone" [requiredValidator]="true"
                                       formControlName="Phone" name="PhoneHtmlId" [mask]="{ mask: '999-999-9999', placeholder: '___-___-____', clearIfNotMatch: false }" />
                            </div>
```

It is a masked text box. I need a patternValidator that is regex to avoid it.
Can you please help me in writing regex for the same.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the job

```
^(?!000-000-0000)$
```

for you reference:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

**EDIT**: Based on the comment, you are looking for the following:

```
^[1-9]{3}-[1-9]{3}-[1-9]{4}$
```

Comment: It's not working. It is not even accepting 111-234-5678

Comment: No this will not accept even 000-000-0011 all digits should not be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

```
/^(?!000-000-0000)[0-9-]{12}$/
```

it will accept everything except all zero.

Please refer the below plunger and replace the ng-pattern data with the above regex.

[Plunger for the demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/laB3Q7nApuoLT9NYnCGX)